# How to add a new word to the string values in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have an issue with lists, I have a list `lst =['ab', 'cd', 'ef']`. Now I want to add a string (`'are'`)to end of each string value of the list. I tried but it is getting added letter by letter, how to add the whole word to end of each string value in the list?

My code:

```
lst =['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
b = 'are'
new_list =  [el1+'_'+el2 for el2 in b for el1 in lst]
```

It gives:

```
new_list = ['ab_a', 'cd_a', 'ef_a','ab_r', 'cd_r', 'ef_r','ab_e', 'cd_e', 'ef_e']
```

Excepted output:

```
new_list = ['ab_are', 'cd_are', 'ef_are']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than iterate on the second string just append like

```
new_list =  [el1+'_'+ b for el1 in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lst =['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
b = 'are'

new = ["_".join([item, b]) for item in lst]

# ['ab_are', 'cd_are', 'ef_are']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through both list and string. Just iterate through the list:

```py
lst =['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
b = 'are'
new_list =  [el + '_' + b for el in lst]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```py
['ab_are', 'cd_are', 'ef_are']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate in list

```
    lst = ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
    b = "are"
    iterated_list = [i + " " + b for i in lst]
    print(iterated_list)
```

Another option would be the following below:

```
   lst = ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
   b = "are"
   iterated_list = []
   for i in lst:
       iterated_list.append(i + " " + b)

   print(iterated_list)
```